# Executes functions async series

Tags: javascript, node.js, series

I'm trying to executes two functions async series with node.JS.
But I don't understand to do this.

Now, I have:

function 1:

```
function search(client_id, callback) {
    clientRedis.keys('director:*', function (err, results) {
        results.forEach(function (key) {
            clientRedis.hgetall(key, function (err, obj) {
                //SAVE RESULT
                console.log('save');
            });
        });
    });
    callback(null, results);
}
```

function 2:

```
function range(client_id, callback) {
    //Sort my array
    callback(null, results);
}
```

And I call this functions here:

```
async.series([
    search(client_id),
    range(client_id);
], function (err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

My problem: Second function is execute before the first because the first take more time. I need the result to first function to range my array with the function 2.

Comment: On a side note, are you aware that using `redis.keys` isn't recommended in production because it scans *all* the keys?

Comment: So, what can I use ?

Comment: You're not gonna like the answer: it depends. What are you fetching there? Some object ids? Data? Ranged data, sets, serialized objects?

Comment: I make a list with hmset command. Inside I have this format: {ID, 'latitude', NUMBER, "longitude", NUMBER}. And I want to range by distance all IDs in this list But I can't make a "range" on a list hmset so I use a array with ZADD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't going to use results of the first function inside the second one directly (only via redis) you can use something like this:

```
async.series([
    search.bind(null, client_id),
    range.bind(null, client_id)
], function (err, results) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results[0]); // for search results
    console.log(results[1]); // for range results
});
```

Comment: Please, what is bind ?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

`search(client_id)` and `range(client_id)` will execute immediately, have `callback` argument assigned to `undefined` then `async.series` will try to execute the results of those functions as a series, and probably fail because those aren't functions, but `undefined`. Or rather, it would, if the functions didn't try to do `undefined(null, results)`.

Keep in mind, if `f` is a function, `f(...)` executes it. You need to pass functions themselves to `async.series`, not results of their execution.

`async.series` wants you to pass in an array or object of tasks, each task being `function(callback) { ... }`.

Thus, the following should help:

```
async.series([
     function(callback) { search(client_id, callback); },
     function(callback) { range(client_id, callback); }
]...)
```

If you were writing in Haskell, that supports currying, your code would have been correct; but in JavaScript, `f(x)(y)` is not the same thing as `f(x, y)`.

You also don't call `callback` from inside the Redis success function, which will also mess up your timing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `async.waterfall` instead of `async.series` to get first function result in second function.

> Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their results to the next in the array. However, if any of the tasks pass an error to their own callback, the next function is not executed, and the main callback is immediately called with the error.

And, you have a big mistakes in your code. If I understand your code, you want go to the second function after modify all your results and return this for the second function right ? In this case, use `async.each` instead of `result.forEach` and call the callback after the async each :

```
function search(client_id, callback) {
    clientRedis.keys('director:*', function (err, results) {
        var savedElems = [];
        async.each(results, function (key, done) {
            clientRedis.hgetall(key, function (err, obj) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                savedElems.push(obj);
                done();
            });
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            callback(null, savedElems);
        });
    });
}
```